# Comment only posting to my wall, not PAGE

Tags: comments, facebook-javascript-sdk

ok:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=121106444664072";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Inferno-Online-Stockholm/149232401793444" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

But the comment goes to my personal wall, not to "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Inferno-Online-Stockholm/149232401793444" wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code creates a comments plugin where users can comment on the url 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/Inferno-Online-Stockholm/149232401793444' - this is probably not what you want as the comments will only be shown on the user's wall (if they choose to post there) and the comment plugin itself.

I don't believe there's any plugin that allows users to post onto your Facebook page from the plugin directly, if you want users to write on the page wall for some reason, you'll need to send them to the page

Comment: Sigh, I was afraid you would say that.